# New Contract Javscript Button - Number Conversion Error

Tags: javascript, custom-button

**Problem Summary**

I added a <kbd>Create Contract</kbd> `Javascript Button` to the `Opportunity Page Layout`. Once a user clicks on the button, it should create a new `Contract` with data populated from the `Opportunity`.

**Layout**

[image: Layout Screenshot]

**Error**

> A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:
>
> {faultcode:'soapenv:Client', faultstring:''USD 2.00' is not valid for the type xsd:dobule', }

**Button Script**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js')} 

var contract = new sforce.SObject('Contract'); 
contract.Net_License__c = '{!Opportunity.Net_License__c }';
contract.Net_Maintenance_Amount__c = '{!Opportunity.Maintenance_Amount__c}';
contract.Net_Consulting_Amount__c = '{!Opportunity.Services_Amount__c }';
contract.Net_Training_Amount__c = '{!Opportunity.Net_Training_Amount__c}';
contract.Deal_Total_cal__c = '{!Opportunity.P_Amount__c}';
contract.OppOpp__c = '{!Opportunity.Opportunity_No__c}';

result = sforce.connection.create([contract]); 

if(result[0].success == 'true') {
    window.location = '/' + result[0].id ;
}
else {
    alert('Error');
}
```

Comment: This error indicates the value 'USD 2.00' is not a valid number.  Probably because you have 'USD' in there.  What is the data type of the fields you are trying to assign each value?  Do they match the data type of the opportunity fields?

Comment: @Berg - all are Currency (16, 2) in both ends (Opportunity and Contract). Rregarding USD, in my org multiple currency feature is enabled, so on selection bases the currency will automatically change.

Comment: Ok, can you test without 'USD' in your opportunity fields?  Try using your button with just '2.00' as each value.

Comment: @berg - getting the same error in the currency field  ---> {Faultcode: 'soapenv: Client', faultstring: "$2.00" is not valid for the type xsd:double',}

Comment: @SachinKumar drop the $

Comment: @Eric - its currency field, so taking automatically ($).

Answer (score 0):

At a basic level, all you have to do is replace all the non-digit characters (except `.`) so that you can parse the `String` into a `Float`. The resulting regex is `/[^\.\d]/g`. Try adopting the following approach:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js')} 
var regex = new RegExp('[^\\.\\d]', 'g'),
    sanitize = new function (currency) {
        return parseFloat(currency.replace(regex, ''));
    },
    contract = new sforce.SObject('Contract'),
    result;

contract.Net_License__c = sanitize('{!Opportunity.Net_License__c }';
contract.Net_Maintenance_Amount__c = sanitize('{!Opportunity.Maintenance_Amount__c}');
contract.Net_Consulting_Amount__c = sanitize('{!Opportunity.Services_Amount__c }');
contract.Net_Training_Amount__c = sanitize('{!Opportunity.Net_Training_Amount__c}');
contract.Deal_Total_cal__c = sanitize('{!Opportunity.P_Amount__c}');
contract.OppOpp__c = sanitize('{!Opportunity.Opportunity_No__c}');

result = sforce.connection.create([contract]);
if(result[0].success == 'true') {
    window.location = '/' + result[0].id;
}
else {
    alert('Error');
}
```